# What is "locks(micros) w:16035" and "locks(micros) r:10051" in the mongodb log

Tags: mongodb

I have enabled profiling in the MongoDb config file.

```
profile=2
slowms=5
```

The mongodb log contains all the queries that took longer than 5 milliseconds (weird, I thought profile=2 meant log ALL queries).

For all `update` entries, the line ends with `locks(micros) w:17738 17ms` (the actual number varies). For all the `query` entries, the line contains `locks(micros) r:15208`

Sample line

```
Tue Dec 03 02:29:43.084 [conn11] update DbName.CollectionName query: { _id: ObjectId('51dfd2791bbdbe0b44395553')} update: { json for new document } nscanned:1 nmoved:1 nupdated:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) w:17738 17ms
```

Reading the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-profiler/), I found the following section,

> system.profile.lockStats
>
> ```
> New in version 2.2.
>
> The time in microseconds the operation spent acquiring and holding locks. This field reports data for the following lock types:
>
>     R - global read lock
>     W - global write lock
>     r - database-specific read lock
>     w - database-specific write lock
> ```

Okay, so the `r` & `w` are some database-specific lock times. But which one? **Is it time spent holding the lock or time spent waiting to acquire a lock?**

Comment: it's the time holding the lock.   you are reading section about the profile collection which has two numbers for each query, one labeled Acquiring and the other labeled Locked.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky, any links to back that up? If I were looking at the corresponding entry in the profile collection, then yes, I would see the two properties you mentioned. However in the log file, it only mentions `w`. I was hoping for a link that mentions what the various fields of the log file are.

Answer (score 6):

> profile=2
> slowms=5
>
> The mongodb log contains all the queries that took longer than 5 milliseconds (weird, I thought profile=2 meant log ALL queries).

Setting *profile* to level 2 means that all queries are included in the `system.profile` capped collection irrespective of the *slowms* value.  This does not affect what queries will be included in the `mongod` log.

Setting *slowms* to 5ms defines the threshold for slow queries that will be logged (irrespective of profiling) and included in the `system.profile` collection if *profile* is level 1 (i.e. profile slow queries).

If you want to see queries in your logs as well, you can increase the loglevel to 1 or higher:

```
db.adminCommand( { setParameter: 1, logLevel: 1 } )
```

WARNING: increased log levels get *very* noisy, and the logs are not capped like the `system.profile` collection!

> Okay, so the r & w are some database-specific lock times. But which one? Is it time spent holding the lock or time spent waiting to acquire a lock?

For the `system.profile.lockStats` there are separate fields for acquiring (`timeAcquiringMicros`) and holding (`timeLockedMicros`) locks.

The "locks(micros)" details in the log are only showing the timeLockedMicros details (source reference: [db/lockstat.cpp](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v2.4/src/mongo/db/lockstat.cpp#L40).

> I was hoping for a link that mentions what the various fields of the log file are

I'm not aware of any detailed documentation for the log file format, and there are definitely some variations between major MongoDB releases. A great open source toolkit for working with MongoDB log files is [`mtools`](https://github.com/rueckstiess/mtools). You could peek into the code there to see how it parses different log lines.